# Copy file from remote UNIX terminal to local system

Tags: unix, remote-connection

I  use putty on Vista to connect to remote UNIX shell. But I want to copy files from that remote server to my local Vista system. How to do that??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net) should do the trick. You're not going to be able to do it form putty.

Answer (score 3):

Use PSCP; PuTTY Secure Copy. If you can connect via SSH there is PuTTY and then 99 times out of 100 if you can SSH you can also SCP(Secure Copy).

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PuTTY and connecting via SSH check if you have pscp installed with PuTTY (or download it from the PuTTY site). Then you can just do:

pscp user@host:/path/to/file .

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since this was asked, but I just happened to pull this off fairly easily with a couple utilities without an extra SCP/SFTP session.

- Set up port forwarding in your SSH session for some remote port `portA` to forward to some local port `portB`.
- Run `netcat` (or an equivalent such as `ncat`) on your local machine, making it listen to `portB` and output to a file:

  ```
  nc -l -p portB > output_file
  ```
- Run `netcat` (or, again, an equivalent such as `ncat`) on the remote host, piping in data however you wish to `localhost:portA`.

  ```
  nc localhost portA -q 1 < my_file
  # or maybe, say, mysqldump --xml ... ... | nc localhost portA -q 1
  ```
- The `netcat`s will both exit when the file has been completely received.

You can of course add a `gzip` or a `pv` inbetween. Do remember the connection only accepts one file at a time -- creative use of `tar` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin + scp/ftp?

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY comes with a program called PSFTP, which is the PuTTY equivalent of SFTP. This is superior to any of the `scp`-based solutions.